# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ulong[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to save ulong[] to my json file.

This is my code:

```
ulong[] ts = new ulong[3];
ts[0] = 749076952626757682
ts[1] = 849076952626757682
ts[2] = 949076952626757682

var json = string.Empty;
json = File.ReadAllText(@"file.json");
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

jsonObj["whitelistedChannels"] = ts; //this is the line on which i'm getting the error
tring output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(configFile, output);
```

This is my json

```
{
  "test": []
}
```

I want my json file to look like this:

```
{
  "test": [749076952626757682,849076952626757682,949076952626757682]
}
```

How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you the error you mentioned in the title?

Comment: @Sweeper 
jsonObj["test"] = ts;

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(configFile, output);

Comment: You should [edit] that into your question. Also, please show _all_ the necessary code. What is `jsonObj`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Why do you deserialize an empty json, only to stuff data into the resulting object, only to serialize it back to json? How about just constructing the class you can just serialize, and skipping the whole deserialization part? A simple `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { test = ts })` would do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to create a special class to represent your json structure, you  can deserialize to `JObject` and use `Add` method to add new property using `JToken.FromObject`:

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json); // or use `JObject.Parse`
ulong[] ts = new ulong[3];
ts[0] = 749076952626757682;
ts[1] = 849076952626757682;
ts[2] = 949076952626757682;
jObj.Add("whitelistedChannels", JToken.FromObject(ts));
```

or set existing one like this (actually will work for addition also):

```
jObj["test"] = JToken.FromObject(ts);
```

Comment: It is saving only the ts[0].
"test": [
    749076952626757682
  ]

Comment: @Dakata it [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31yKea) for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ulong[] ts = new ulong[3];
ts[0] = 749076952626757682;
ts[1] = 849076952626757682;
ts[2] = 949076952626757682;

var obj = new { test = ts };

//pick only one of the next two lines
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); //from Newtonsoft.Json
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj); //from System.Text.Json

File.WriteAllText("filename.json", json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to deserialize the content of your file and then add the data with the existing data and rewrite it to the file. Below is the sample code

Create a class

```
public class DataToWrite
{
   public List<ulong> whitelistedChannels { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your code

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"file.json");
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

jsonObj.whitelistedChannels.AddRange(ts);
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(configFile, output);
```

Initial data in the file

```
{
  "whitelistedChannels": []
}
```

After writing data to your file

```
{
  "whitelistedChannels": [
    749076952626757682,
    849076952626757682,
    949076952626757682
  ]
}
```